# Is there an efficient way to read named ranges from Excel into Python? My runtime is excruciatingly long

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an Excel file with several sheets and lots of named ranges. Those are different parameters which I want to feed into a model I am developing with Python. Now the question is how I can make those parameters available in Python within a reasonable time.

I have tried different modules for reading the Excel data in Python and the one I am most comfortable with is openpyxl (which also seems like one of the most popular).
The issue I am having now is the runtime which is unbearably long. For a range of just 300 rows x 100 columns = 30,000 cells it takes more than 30min, which is frustrating since other programs can read those data within seconds.
I am not an expert in Python or data structures so I appreciate any hint, where I could improve my code, so it won't take several hours for bigger ranges.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True, read_only=True)

parameter_names = [i.name for i in wb.get_named_ranges()]
parameters = {}
for parameter in parameter_names:
    ws, cellrange = next(wb.defined_names[parameter].destinations)
    if len(wb[ws][cellrange][0]) > 1:
        parameters[parameter] = [[wb[ws][cellrange][row][column].value for column in range(len(wb[ws][cellrange][row]))] for row in range(len(wb[ws][cellrange]))]
    else:
        parameters[parameter] = [wb[ws][cellrange][row][0].value for row in range(len(wb[ws][cellrange]))]
```

It would be great if someone who had a similar problem or just knows how to deal with such issues can share their insights. Either by showing me how I can modify my own code (which would be ideal) or by suggesting a different approach. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `wb.get_named_ranges()` and `wb.defined_names`. I suspect performance issues are related to the loops. Would be easier to discuss on the mailing list with a file.

Comment: @CharlieClark I use `wb.get_named_ranges()`for identifying the parameters in the Excel file and `wb.defined_names`to access them one at a time. Don't know how I could do it more efficiently. Thanks for the hint, but at the moment I can't figure out what you mean by mailing list. I'm new to this.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Sample use for ranges](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html?highlight=defined_names)

Comment: There is a link to the openpyxl mailing list from the documentation.